# How and where to change color of table rows in console?

Tags: console, customization

I have console on my website where I can see list of messages. I want to change color of each row based on "Owner First Name" column. So if owner is Mary then the row must be green for example.
How can I achieve this? 
P.S. I could solve it with JS but I don't know how to find code of this table. Where can I edit code of this console?
[image]

Comment: Can you acess the code where this table is built? In other words, is this a visualforce page?

Comment: I have no access ) I can't find it.

Comment: Console is a package but I can't find this apex page.

Comment: Without access to the code its kind of difficult. Does the package have some sort of layout manager where you can see what's in that tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually "Console 1.0", the original iteration of the current console. It's a very old product and no longer supported as of several years ago. This must be a very old org :)

What you're seeing is not a Visualforce page but actually a core Salesforce page. There isn't any way for you to access the code or change its appearance via apex or anything like that. A client side modification via JS would be the only option for altering its appearance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you tell me where can I modify JS?

Comment: I have an idea that I could paste JS to left sidebar but I don't know how to add custom page to sidebar on Console page. I know only how to add it on Homepage...